# wordpress: Script timed out before returning headers: index.php

Tags: php, wordpress

In log file i get this error:

> Script timed out before returning headers: index.php.

I get:

> internal server error 500 (frontend and backend),

I have try:

1. disable plugin
2. disable theme
3. restore database
4. restore core wordpress file
5. check htaccess

nothing...the site work in safari...but get internal server error 500 in chrome and firefox.

Comment: If you had a caching plugin like w3 total cache or something similar. Check your .htaccess file and see if there is anything to do with the caching plugin in their. You will see something like "#BEGIN W3TC Browser Cache" or something similar depending on the plugin. If this is the case just remove the entries created by the plugin.

Comment: this is my htaccess file:

Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: I have remove all plugin cache...

Comment: Please don't post large code-like blocks in comments. Edit your question instead.

Comment: the link is this: tasteandgo.com, in safari work..in chrome and Firefox not work..
I can not understand the problem ..